# Por que o resultado da média sempre fica "NaN"?

Tags: javascript, tipagem

Tenho um problema em calcular a média de diversas notas digitadas pelo usuário.

A função retorna apenas NaN.

```js
function calcularMedia() {

  var nota = parseInt(prompt("Digite uma nota:"));

  for (;;) {
    var soma = nota + soma;
    var num = num + 1;
    var dec = parseInt(prompt("Deseja continuar? Digite 1 para 'SIM' ou 2 para 'NÃO':"));

    if (dec == 2) {
      var media = parseInt((soma / num));
      alert('A média das notas digitadas é: ' + media);
      break;
    } else {
      calcularMedia();
    }
  }
}

calcularMedia();
```

Comment: Qual o valor inicial de `num`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

O código é bem confuso. Primeiro precisa declarar as variáveis que acumulam e contam for do laço, e seria bom inicializar com 0 pra deixar mais explícito que está é a intenção.

Além disso está pedindo a nota fora do laço, então pede só uma vez e isso não faz sentido.

Chamar a função de novo se deseja continuar não é adequado e vai estourar o *stack* em algum momento se tiver muitos dados para serem digitados. Não vai dar problema no exercício, mas pra que aprender fazer errado?

Corrigi essas coisas e resolveu, mas ainda não estou tratando um possível erro se a pessoa digitar algo onválido, o correto é cuidar disso no código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exercício 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
    function calcularMedia() {
        var soma = 0;
        var contador = 0;
        for(;;) {
            var nota = parseInt(prompt("Digite uma nota:"));
            soma += nota;
            contador++;
            var dec = parseInt(prompt("Deseja continuar? Digite 1 para 'SIM' ou 2 para 'NÃO':"));
            if (dec == 2) {
                alert('A média das notas digitadas é: ' + parseInt(soma / contador));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>calcularMedia();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/CalcAverage.js).

O código original dele era esse então deixei assim.

Answer (score 0):

O erro NaN significa "not a number", ou seja, em algum lugar do seu código não está sendo identificado um número.

Exemplo:

```
parseInt('ab') vai dar NaN
parseInt('1') vai dar 1
```